# Not able to change pagination selected page color to grey using material UI pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, pagination

I am using pagination from material UI, I changed all page color to white but not able to change the selected page color to grey, It is not properly displayed as background color is dark.

```react
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';
import { Box, Typography, Stack } from '@mui/material';

import { exercisesOptions, fetchData } from '../utils/fetchData';
import ExerciseCard from './ExerciseCard';

const Exercises = ({ exercises, setExercises, bodyPart }) => {
   const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
   const exercisesPerPage = 9;

    const indexOfLastExercise = currentPage * exercisesPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstExercise = indexOfLastExercise - exercisesPerPage;
    const currentExercises =  exercises.slice(indexOfFirstExercise, indexOfLastExercise);
   const paginate = (e, value)=>{
      setCurrentPage(value);
      window.scrollTo({top:1800, behavior: 'smooth'})
   };

    return (
        <Box
            id="exercises"
            sx={{ mt: { lg: '109px' } }}
            mt="50px"
            p='20px'
            backgroundColor ="#001C30"
        >
           
            <Stack mt='100px' alignItems='center'>
              {exercises.length > 9 && (
                <Pagination 
                    color="standard"
                    shape="rounded"
                    defaultPage={1}
                    count={Math.ceil(exercises.length/
                    exercisesPerPage)}
                    page={currentPage}
                    onChange={paginate}
                    size="large"
                    sx={{
                        button:{color: '#ffffff'},
                      }}
                />
              )}
            </Stack>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default Exercises
```

I wanted to get the background color of current page as like this
[image: I wanted to change the current page background color to grey something like this]

But I am getting like this

[image: but I am getting like this]

Answer (score 0):

I think we need further informations about our problems. However, I think your color displays well (I can see a little grey circle), but there's not enough contrast between the two colors for the gray circle to be seen properly.

Comment: yeah that is the problem here as the background color is too dark can't properly seen the grey color.

Comment: Maybe it's going to help you a little, but for me I had a theme preloaded in my app. The theme was overidding some elements.